# Selenium using Python can't click an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[Browser Dev Tools Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Tix.png)

I am trying to click the following button, I have the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver.get(
    "SITE")
driver.execute_script(
    "return document.getElementById('attentive_overlay').remove();")
driver.find_element(
    By.ID, "search_bar_input").send_keys("preservation kit")
driver.find_element(
    By.ID, "search_bar_input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

atbb = driver.find_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-test-id='product_add_to_bag']")
```

I usually get this error.

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button class="buttonstyled__ButtonStyled-sc-1raww7j-0 lmuxzm sc-98482ff5-4 gjMHqx" type="submit"> could not be scrolled into view`

Which, I've tried to resolve using this doc: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html?highlight=move_to_element#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element

```
atbb = driver.find_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-test-id='product_add_to_bag']")

driver.move_to_element(atbb)

driver.atbb.click()
```

but I now get this error:

`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'move_to_element'`

but I can't seem to get it working past that.  Any assistance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")

actions = ActionChains(driver) 
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```